# Price history with chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have this kind of data array:

```
[
   {
      "price":"49",
      "date":"21\/01\/2018"
   },
   {
      "price":"30",
      "date":"01\/01\/2018"
   },
   {
      "price":"32",
      "date":"15\/11\/2017"
   }
]
```

Now I want to create a chart with [chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/), that shows me a price curve for the last 12 month.

I wrote this little script to generate me the past months:

```
function getPreviousMonths() {
    var months = [];

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        var month = moment().subtract(i, 'months').format('MMMM Y');
        months.push(month);
    }
    return months.reverse();
}
```

How can I create the chartjs chart now? I looked in the docs, but got very confused when it comes to set dates within axes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html for setting time scale on xAxes, then you have to convert your date field to a real date object:

```
  xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    distribution: 'linear',
    ticks: {
      source: 'labels'
    },
    time: {
    unit: 'month',
    unitStepSize: 1,
    displayFormats: {
       'month': 'MMM'
      }
    }
  }
```

Check this jsfiddle showing an example of time serie rendered as a line: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/9f9a2z88/

Comment: But the thing is, that I want to have the months as the label and then show the dates of the price changes accordingly. I don't want the labels to be the date, the price changed.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! Only two things are left: Display the label of a data point in custom date format (e.g DD.MM.YYYY) and see the current value at all points, so not only having a tooltip on the data points, but everywhere. Would be awesome, if you could help me on that one as well .
I made some little changes already: https://jsfiddle.net/Zoker/voc3w8n4/

Comment: Here is a new [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/7kwofvj4/) with custom tooltip label formatting (using momentjs). Besides the `tooltips: { mode: 'nearest',  intersect: false, }` option shows tooltips also on lines. I hope it helps

Comment: Why is there an Invalid date in 2022 in the example?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 separate your data array into 2 different arrays. One of dates (say dates_array) and another of price (say price_array). Then you just have to create new chart.

```
var chart = new Chart(element, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: dates_array,
      datasets: [{
        label: '# price',
        data: price_array
      }]
    }
  });
```

Here, element is the element in which chart will be shown. `labels` will be assigned the date array and `data` will be assigned price array. You can check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j7gta8yn/

Comment: But the thing is, I don't want to use the dates as a lable. I want to use the past 11 month as a lable and then show the dates accordingly in the chart.